# How to get logs from AWS API Destinations

Tags: aws-event-bridge

I have AWS API Destination, which is triggered by rule. I attached DLQ to rule and I am getting rejected messages, but I don't see any reason why this is happening.
Is there any way to get logs in Cloud Watch about errors in API Destinations/Connections?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no facility to see/log the API Destination responses in EventBridge.
I've been searching for exactly the same and come up empty.

The workaround for now is to instead target a lambda that does the API call instead.

Comment: I can not tell you how frustrating this is.  Without logging, API destinations are essentially useless.